# BeautifulSoup not finding dates

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from here: https://www.reuters.com/companies/AMPF.MI/financials/income-statement-quarterly.

I'd like to get the dates in the first row (ie. 31-Mar-21   31-Dec-20   30-Sep-20   30-Jun-20   31-Mar-20).

The problem comes when I try to get the date, with bs4 it outputs nothing. I wrote this code:

```
url = "https://www.reuters.com/companies/AMPF.MI/financials/income-statement-quarterly"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup (html_content, "lxml")

a = soup.find('div', attrs = {"class": "tables-container"})
date = a.find("time").text;
```

When I execute it, it gives me nothing. Printing a, it can be seen that the find () doesn't get the date ... `

```
<th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"></time>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Can you please send us a screenshot from the element you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't enought reputation for sendig images. I'd like to get only the dates. (31-Mar-21 31-Dec-20 30-Sep-20 30-Jun-20 31-Mar-20). Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using css selectors to fetch dates directly: `soup.select("div.tables-container th time")`, than you can interate over them and do whatever you want with `.text`

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry, but I did't get it yet. I also tried to soup.find('time', attrs={"class":"TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"}). But the result was the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is embedded within the page in JSON form. You can use this example how to parse it:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reuters.com/companies/AMPF.MI/financials/income-statement-quarterly"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

x = data["props"]["initialState"]["markets"]["financials"]["financial_tables"]

headers = x["income_interim_tables"][0]["headers"]
print(*headers, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
2021-03-31
2020-12-31
2020-09-30
2020-06-30
2020-03-31
```

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have enough reputation to comment:

The problem is that the scraped HTML does not contain the dates. The `time` tags are empty.

You need a way to scrape while pre-rendering the JavaScript which fills in the dates. This is a different topic which requires some headless browser or other approaches, e.g. https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/scrapy-javascript/